# how to pass event across windows, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I would like to achieve the following UI affect, really appreciated for your help or hint.

1) When a link is clicked, a window pops up to its side (preferably relative to the position of the link instead of being fixed). The link is pointed to a php-based URL.

2) The pop-up window should have some "relation" or same "name space" to the original window, for instance, passing mouse events, cross-window "scroll to", etc.

It is doable across div's, I am just not sure if it is also true across different windows. I don't even find something to try with.

I am not an expert of jQuery or Web design in general, so please give your advice with sufficient details for me start. Thanks a lot.

---

Regarding the answers...

First of all, thank you! I am currently testing "opener"...
When I am doing this, I wonder if objects from different windows can be referenced.
For example the following code,

```
function mse_over()
{
  $('#'+object).css('border', '2px ridge brown');
}
```

which simply changes the border color of an object.

My question is in child window, can it be done if the object is in parent window (and vice versa). One way doable might be to call "mse_over" from child. But is it possible to directly access objects cross windows? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a window is opened via a link, it is certainly doable to manage the content both from the child to the parent and the reverse.

You need to assign the child window to a javascript object. This example opens a new window and then changes the title of the window:

```
child_window = window.open('test.php');

$(child_window.document).ready(function () {
  $(child_window.document).contents().find('#title').html('New title');
});
```

Likewise, you can manage the parent by assigning the window.opener to an object:

```
parent_window = window.opener
```

This is core javascript, jQuery just makes some of the selectors and page manipulation a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [window.opener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_parent.asp)
window.opener is a variable holding the window object of the window that opened the current window.

In my examples, I'll assume you're using jQuery. It is not neccessary to use jQuery, but I'm using it to abstract away browser differences.

You could do this in your main window:

```
window.onChildWindowClick = function(e){
    //do stuff with click event
}
```

now in the popup window

```
$("#element-in-popup").click(function(e){
    window.opener.onChildWindowClick(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old question but for now is pretty simple solution:

```
ch = new BroadcastChannel('channel_name');
ch.addEventListener('message', evt => {
    console.log("RECV ->", evt.data);
});
```

and after than You can POST simple message on one window:

```
ch.postMessage("TEST")
```

or more complicated:

```
ch.postMessage({type: "TEST", value: 123456})
```

on other window(s) You should see:

```
RECV -> TEST
RECV -> {type: 'TEST', value: 123456}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/#web-messaging
&
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp
can help you.

Cross-document messaging allows you to pass events between windows. However, cross-site scripting is disallowed.

For parent window:

```
var event = function() {...};
childw = window.open(...);
```

For child windows:

```
window.opener.func();
```

Comment: There is an example in try in yourself @w3schools.com

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities also include using "localStorage."  It will work as long as "origin" is the same, and the browser is from the same vendor.

In one window, create an event-listener with:

`window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {...`

In another window, add or change something via localStorage:

`localStorage.setItem("key", "value");`

You will find that if you try to set an existing item to the same value as before, the event will (from what I have seen) NOT be triggered.

I found the directions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API